# Linguaggio formale ed informale

Tags: formal

Vorrei sapere come sia possibile decidere se una parola è in linguaggio formale o meno. Per esempio, in un contesto formale ho la scelta fra scrivere che un cavo è stato "disconnesso" o "scollegato"; per quanto riguarda il mio gusto e/o sensazione, credo che "disconnesso" sia più formale, ma non riesco a spiegare il perché. Qualcuno può aiutarmi?

Comment: Io mi porrei anche il problema se veramente sia necessario il termine più formale. Si rischia di finire come chi scrive “Eseguiamo il seguente orario...”.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purtroppo il linguaggio non si divide in caselline ben separate ed etichettate. Non è possibile distinguere tutte le espressioni come "formali" o "informali": alcune sono sicuramente formali (e.g. *ottemperare*), altre sicuramente informali (e.g. *fancazzista*), altre una via di mezzo (*eseguire*). Inoltre la maggior parte delle parole non sono né formali né informali: si possono usare in tutti i contesti senza distinzione alcuna.

Nel caso specifico della domanda direi che *disconnesso* e *scollegato* sono egualmente formali. Direi che oltre a motivi tecnici (e.g. se in un particolare contesto hanno significati leggermente diversi) o di eufonia, non v'è motivo per preferire una all'altra.